# Variables overwritten when running a class function

Tags: python, class, variables

I have the following MWE:

```
import numpy as np

class PlainLR:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        
        rng = np.random.default_rng(42)
        init_range = 1.0 / np.sqrt(float(10))
        self.weights = rng.uniform(low=-init_range, high=init_range, size=10)
        self.bias = rng.uniform(low=-init_range, high=init_range, size=1)

        self.plaintext_weights = self.weights
        self.plaintext_bias = self.bias
    
    def get_model_parameters(self):
        return self.plaintext_weights,self.plaintext_bias
    
    def train(self):
        self.weights -= 3* (1 / 5) + self.weights * 10
        self.bias -= 4 * (1 / 5)

plaintextLR = PlainLR()
plaintext_weights, plaintext_bias = plaintextLR.get_model_parameters() # Grab the initial values here
print(plaintext_weights, plaintext_bias)
plaintextLR.train()
print(plaintext_weights, plaintext_bias) # I was expecting here the same output as in the previous print line
```

Can someone explain to me why the two print lines at the end of the code result in different outputs? I was hoping that when I have the line:

```
plaintext_weights, plaintext_bias = plaintextLR.get_model_parameters() # Grab model parameters before training the data to supply the exact same parameters to the encrypted LR model for comparison
```

I store the initialization random values (lines 7-10) to the variables `plaintext_weights, plaintext_bias`, but it seems that by executing the function `train` of the class right afterwards, it overwrites the initial values I stored before. Can someone explain to me why and how I could achieve to store only the initial values to the variables?

Comment: You're dealing with _mutable objects_, maybe `get_model_parameters` should return _copies_ (or more likely copies should be assigned to the `plaintext_`-prefixed attributes).

Comment: @jonrsharpe could you illustrate how I could achieve that?

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.copy.html?

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `self.weights.copy()` and `self.bias.copy()` in place of `self.weights` and `self.bias`.

In addition, you don't need to define `self.plaintext_weights` or `self.plaintext_bias` at all because you can simply return `self.weights.copy()` and `self.bias.copy()` instead.

Your code would look something like this:

```py
import numpy as np

class PlainLR:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        rng = np.random.default_rng(42)
        init_range = 1.0 / np.sqrt(float(10))
        self.weights = rng.uniform(low=-init_range, high=init_range, size=10)
        self.bias = rng.uniform(low=-init_range, high=init_range, size=1)
    
    def get_model_parameters(self):
        return self.weights.copy(), self.bias.copy()
    
    def train(self):
        self.weights -= 3* (1 / 5) + self.weights * 10
        self.bias -= 4 * (1 / 5)

plaintextLR = PlainLR()
plaintext_weights, plaintext_bias = plaintextLR.get_model_parameters()
print(plaintext_weights, plaintext_bias)
plaintextLR.train()
print(plaintext_weights, plaintext_bias)
```